# Ошибка в загрузке данных из файла в структуру

Tags: c++, struct, fstream

В программе я могу заполнить структуры, после сохранить, а затем считать из бинарного файла. Получается так, что если заполнены лишь структуры Кафедр, при чем не важно сколько их, считывается все хорошо. Однако если в одной из Кафедр есть группы, то при чтении названия Кафедр едут, а группы попросту теряются

Структура задана таким образом

```
    struct Student{ 
    char fio1[32];          // Фамилия
    char fio2[32];          // Имя  
    char fio3[32];          // Отчество 
    bool typeOfEducation;   // 0 - бюджет, 1 - коммерция
    int money;              // Оплата либо Стипендия
    Student* next;          // Указатель на следующего студента в группе
    Student* back;          // Указатель на предыдущего
};

struct Group{
    int number;             // Номер группы
    int count;              // счетчик студентов
    Student* first;         // Первый студент в группе
    Student* last;          // Последний
    Group* next;            // Указатель на следующую группу
    Group* back;            // Указатель на предыдущую
};

struct Cathedra{
    char cathedraName[16];  // Название Кафедры
    int count;              // Счетчик групп на Кафедре
    Group* head;            // Указатель на первую группу в списке
    Group* tail;            // Указатель на последнюю
    Cathedra* next;         // Указатель на следующую кафедру
    Cathedra* back;         // Указатель на предыдущую
};

struct List{
    int count;              // Счетчик Кафедр
    Cathedra* head;         // Указатель на первую Кафедру
    Cathedra* tail;         // Указатель на последнюю
};
```

Чтение и запись осуществляется следующим кодом

```
void addCathedra(List *L, Cathedra *C){
    C->next = NULL;                         // Обнуляем указатель на следующую кафедру
    if(L->head != NULL){                    // Если список не пустой
        C->back = L->tail;                  // Добавляем указатель на предыдущую кафедру
        L->tail->next = C;                  // указатель предыдущей кафедры на ту, которую добавляем
        L->tail = C;                        // Указываем на то, что новая Кафедра последняя в листе
    } else {                                // Если же список пустой!
        C->back = NULL;                     // предыдущей кафедры попросту нет
        L->head = L->tail = C;              // говорим что первая и последняя кафедра списка - одно и то же
    }
    C->head = C->tail = NULL;               // обнуляем указатели внутри кафедры на первую и последнюю группу
    C->count = 0;                           // обнуляем счетчик групп в кафедре
    L->count++;                             // К счетчику Кафедр прибавляем 1
}

void addGroup(Cathedra *C, Group * G){
    G->next = NULL;                         // Обнуляем указатель на следующую группу
    if(C->head != NULL){                    // Если список не пустой
        G->back = C->tail;                  // Добавляем указатель на предыдущую группу
        C->tail->next = G;                  // указатель предыдущей группы на ту, которую добавляем
        C->tail = G;                        // Указываем на то, что новая группа последняя в листе
    } else {                                // Если же список пустой!
        G->back = NULL;                     // предыдущей группы попросту нет
        C->head = C->tail = G;              // говорим что первая и последняя группы списка - одно и то же
    }
    G->first = G->last = NULL;              // обнуляем указатели внутри группы на первую и последнюю группу
    G->count = 0;                           // обнуляем счетчик студентов в группе
    C->count++;                             // К счетчику Групп прибавляем 1
}

void addStudent(Group * G, Student * S){
    S->next = NULL;                         // Обнуляем указатель на следующего студента
    if(G->first != NULL){                   // Если список не пустой
        S->back = G->first;                 // Добавляем указатель на предыдущего студента
        G->last->next = S;                  // указатель предыдущего студента на того, которого добавляем
        G->last = S;                        // Указываем на то, что новый студент последний в листе
    } else {                                // Если же список пустой!
        S->back = NULL;                     // предыдущего студента попросту нет
        G->first = G->last = S;             // говорим что первый и последний студенты - одно и то же
    }
    G->count++;                             // К счетчику студентов в группе прибавляем 1
}    
void save(List * L){
        string path = "file.txt";
        ofstream fout;
        fout.open(path, ios::app);
        if(!fout.is_open()) cout << "Error!";
        else {
            fout.write((char*)L, sizeof(List));
            Cathedra *tempC = L->head;
            for(int i = 0; i < L->count; i++){
                fout.write((char*)tempC, sizeof(Cathedra));
                Group *tempG = tempC->head;
                for(int j = 0; j < tempC->count; j++){
                    fout.write((char*)tempG, sizeof(Group));
                    Student *tempS = tempG->first;
                    for(int k = 0; k < tempG->count; k++){
                        fout.write((char*)tempS, sizeof(Student));
                        tempS = tempS->next;
                    }
                    tempG = tempG->next;
                }
                tempC = tempC->next;
            }
            cout << endl << "Данные успешно сохранены!" << endl << endl;
         }
         fout.close();
         showCathedras(L);
    }

    void read(){
        string path = "file.txt";   // путь к файлу с данными
        ifstream fin;               // имя потока 
        fin.open(path);             // открываем поток чтения из файла
        List * L = new List;
        if(fin.is_open()){
            fin.read((char*)L, sizeof(List));
            int count = L->count;
            createList(L);
            for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
                Cathedra *tempC = new Cathedra;
                fin.read((char*)tempC, sizeof(Cathedra));
                addCathedra(L, tempC);
                for(int j = 0; j < tempC->count; j++){
                    Group *tempG = new Group;
                    fin.read((char*)tempG, sizeof(Group));
                    addGroup(tempC, tempG);
                    for(int k = 0; k < tempG->count; k++){
                        Student *tempS = new Student;
                        fin.read((char*)tempS, sizeof(Student));
                        addStudent(tempG, tempS);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else createList(L);
        fin.close();                    // закрываем поток чтения данных
        showCathedras(L);
    }
```

Подозреваю что косяк в записи. Сам ошибку найти не могу

Comment: Проблема все такая же, как и в прошлом вопросе - запись в бинарный файл структуры с указателями. Вам стоит почитать что-нибудь по теме сериализации данных.

Answer (score 0):

В функции чтения из файла обнулялся счетчик до цикла

```
  fin.read((char*)tempC, sizeof(Cathedra));
  addCathedra(L, tempC); //здесь tempC->count = 0
  for(int j = 0; j < tempC->count; j++){
```